# Invalid object type for field "location"

Tags: wordpress, events, schema, structured-data

We're doing structured data and inserted it on the site header. On Schema[.]org there is no error. But on Google search console, it says "Invalid object type for field "location". Why is this happening? Checked the Event Structured Data Guideline by google and we have it correct. Still Google Search Console insists there is. Here's how we inserted the location part:

```js
"location": {
    "@type": "VirtualLocation",
    "url": "https://oursite.com/eventpage/"
  },
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and adding:

```
"eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OnlineEventAttendanceMode"
```

to the json+ld above the location ended up fixing the error message. So you should have something like:

```
...json+ld markup...
"eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OnlineEventAttendanceMode",
  "location": {
    "@type": "VirtualLocation",
    "url": "https://operaonline.stream5.com/"
    },
...json+ld markup...
```

If you omit the eventAttendanceMode attribute or use the wrong value for example OfflineEventAttendanceMode, it will throw that error, so make sure you set it to OnlineEventAttendanceMode